# x64 Assembly Division

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

when I execute the following assembly code in Ubuntu 64 bit I get an Floating point exception (core dumped) Error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {  
int arg1, arg2, quo, rem ;

    printf( "Enter two integer numbers : " );
    scanf( "%d%d", &arg1, &arg2 );

    __asm__ ( "movl $0x0, %%edx;"
              "movl %2, %%eax;"
              "movl %3, %%ebx;"
               "idivl %%ebx;" : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2) );


    printf( "%d / %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, quo );
    printf( "%d %% %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, rem );

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Then you probably divided by 0.

Comment: If your scanf is wrong (and it looks that way to me), then arg2 might be 0. What is scanf returning (the number of arguments converted)? Less than 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your immediate problem is presumably caused by not reading the input properly.

However you also use inline asm wrong. gcc inline asm is a complicated beast, make sure you really need it, and then be prepared to do some reading in the manual.

Your code is bad because you use `ebx` without telling the compiler.

Furthermore, a rule of thumb for gcc inline asm is that if you ever use `mov` you are probably doing it wrong. If you want arguments in specific registers, you should use the appropriate constraints. Another rule is you should almost never use `g` constraint.

Possible fix:

```
__asm__("cdq; idivl %3" : "=a" (quo), "=&d" (rem) : "a" (arg1), "rm" (arg2) );
```

Of course you do not need inline asm to perform a division.

---

Update: Looks like the problem was elsewhere after all, namely that you used `%edx` in your code without informing the compiler. Since the compiler didn't know, it was free to allocate it for the divisor, that is the substitution was `%3 = %edx`. Even though the compiler correctly placed the divisor there, the first thing you did was zero `%edx`, thus destroying the divisor. Later you moved that zero into `%ebx`, and tried to divide by it, hence the exception.

My suggestion used a so-called "earlyclobber" modifier (the `&` in the `=&d`) which signals to the compiler that the code will modify the output in question before using up the inputs, thus the compiler must not place any inputs there. Note that just adding this to your original code is still not enough, because that still leaves `%eax` and `%ebx` similarly problematic.

For next time, remember that you can ask for an assembly listing using `gcc -S` (or you can disassemble using `objdump -d` or inside `gdb`) so you can see what substitutions the compiler made.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I am beginner in this trend and what I need is a very simple level in this domain. The problem has been solved by replacing "d" by "&d" in my code, but I do not understand why. Any explanation, please.

Comment: The `&` signals an early-clobber output operand. It basically stops the compiler from allocating the same register for an input. Without it the compiler was free to load one of the arguments into `edx`, which you zeroed and then divided by.